# Where is IdentityHostingStartup.cs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

In VS 2022 I have ASP.NET Core Web App MVC (.NET 6). I chose "Individual Accounts" authorization type. I need to change **IdentityHostingStartup.cs**.

I Already added Scaffolded Item "Identity". This created  the razor pages I needed. But didn't create IdentityHostingStartup.cs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4IG5.png

If create it yourself it is not overridden. So please help me someone, where can I find this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After test, we can't find `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` in .net6 project.

It seems to be removed in .net6 project.